# Any extension for formatting multi-line comments?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, format, comments

In Visual Studio, given the following XML doc comments of a C# method:

```
/// <summary>
/// First line is very long long long long long long long long,
/// and the second is short.
/// </summary>
void Method()
```

Is there any extension that does automatic format of the above comments so that there are no overly long lines? Like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// First line is very long long long long long
/// long long long and the second is short.
/// </summary>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this, add `para` which actually formats the comments in paragraphs.

```
/// <summary>
/// First line is very long long long long long
/// <para>long long long and the second is short.</para>
/// </summary>
void Method()
```

Upon hovering, while calling this method, summary comments are arranged in multiple lines, as shown in below image:

[image]

---

Specific to Visual Studio extensions, [Rewrap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stkb.rewrap) & [Auto Comment Blocks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kevinkyang.auto-comment-blocks) can be used.

> **Rewrap**
>
> Reformats code comments and other text to a given line length. For VSCode and Visual Studio.
>
> **Auto Comment Blocks**
>
> Provides block comment completion for Javadoc-style multi-line comments and single-line comment blocks for most officially supported languages.

***Rewrap is what you need.***

Comment: Ah, thanks for your answer but that's not what I want. Adding para still requires me to manual edit the comment lines. I want an extension that does that trivial work for me automatically.

Comment: Then [Rewrap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stkb.rewrap) & [Auto Comment Blocks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kevinkyang.auto-comment-blocks) might help you.

Comment: Thanks, Rewrap is the right one for me. How do I mark your comment as answer?

Comment: Comments can't be marked as answer. I have edited by answer. You can up-vote it and mark it as suitable answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this also with [VSdocman](https://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html) extension (disclaimer, I'm the author). It does many other things but it can also re-wrap your XML doc comments. Just open its [WYSIWYG comment editor](https://www.helixoft.com/files/vsdocman/help/comeditorwysiwyg.html) and close it. It will wrap the lines according to your [settings](https://www.helixoft.com/files/vsdocman/help/comeditoroptions.html).